# If $\|F(x,y)\|\geq 1$ for all $(x,y)$ such that $\|(x,y)\|=1$, is $F(U)$ closed where $U$ is the open disk?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This is an old qual problem that showed up several times in 2002 and 2003.

> Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a $C^1$ function such that the Jacobian matrix is everywhere nonsingular. Suppose $F(0)=0$ and $\|F(x,y)\|\geq 1$ for all $(x,y)$ such that $\|(x,y)\|=1$. Let $U=\{(x,y):\|(x,y)\|<1\}.$ Show $U\subseteq F(U)$.

I'm just trying to show that $F(U)\cap U$ is both open and closed in $U$ and then appeal to the fact that $U$ is connected.

If $y_0\in F(U)$, then $y_0=F(x_0)$ for some $x_0$, and $F'(x_0)$ is invertible by hypothesis. By the inverse function theorem, there exists an open neighborhood $U_0$ of $x_0$ and an open neighborhood $V_0$ of $y_0$ such that $F(U_0)=V_0$ is a bijection. But then I have
$$
y_0=F(x_0)\in F(U_0\cap U)=F(U_0)\cap F(U)=V_0\cap F(U)\subseteq F(U)
$$
Since $V_0\cap F(U)$ is open in $F(U)$, it follows that $F(U)$ is open, so $F(U)\cap U$ is open in $U$.

Is there a way to show $F(U)\cap U$ is also closed? I tried showing in contains all its limit points without success. I'm confused because there is a hint saying to show $F(U)\cap U$ is both open and closed in $U$, but I think this implies $F(U)$ is both closed and open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which seems wrong since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is also connected.

Comment: You won't be able to show that $F(U)$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$. If it were, and since it is also open in $\mathbb R^2$, then $F(U)$ would be the whole plane. Which isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @Arthur: consider e.g. $F(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2, 0)$... the Jacobian condition is quite important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proved already that $F(U)$ is open (by observing that $F$ is an open map). If now $\bar U$ is the closed unit disk then $F(\bar U)$ is compact, as $\bar U$ is compact; in particular, $F(\bar U)$ is closed, hence $F(\bar U)\cap U$ is closed in $U$. But $F(\bar U)\cap U=F(U)\cap U$.